# Best Handle Intraday GA Data in BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a configured google analytics raw data export to big query.

Could anyone from the community suggest efficient ways to query the intraday data as we noticed the problem for Intraday Sync (e.g. 15 minutes delay), the streaming data is growing exponentially across the sync frequency.

For example:

- Everyday (T-1) batch data (ga_sessions_yyymmdd) syncs with 15-20GB with 3.5M-5M records.
- On the other side, the intraday data streams (with 15 min delay) more than ~150GB per day with ~30M records.

[image]
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117064598

It's not cost-effective for persisting & querying the data.

And, is this a product bug or expected behavior as the data is not cost-effectively usable for exponentially growing data?

Querying big query cost $5 per TB & streaming inserts cost ~$50 per TB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my vision, it is not a bug, it is a consequence of how data is structured in Google Analytics.

Each row is a session, and inside each session you have a number of hits. As we can't afford to wait until a session is completely finished, everytime a new hit (or group of hits) occurs the whole session needs to be exported again to BQ. Updating the row is not an option in a streaming system (at least in BigQuery).

I have already created some stream pipelines in Google Dataflow with Session Windows (not sure if it is what Google uses internally), and I faced the same dilemma: wait to export the aggregate only once, or export continuously and have the exponential growth.

An advice that I can give you about querying the ga_realtime_sessions table is:

- Only query for the columns you really need (no select *);
- use the view that is exported in conjunction with the daily ga_realtime_sessions_yyyymmdd, it doesn't affect the size of the query, but it will prevent you from using duplicated data.

Comment: I believe we don't have any other better options other than this. Thanks